# Decimal Cut problem

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

Is it possible to cut decimal, and not round it. Like this.

```
decimal number = 12.159m;
```

How can I easily get 12.15 from `number` and not 12.16?

Is there an easy way or is the string manipulation the only way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this

```
decimal number = 12.159m;
number = Math.Truncate(number * 100m) / 100m;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
Math.Floor(number * 100) / 100
```

Depending on how you want to handle (if you want to handle) negative numbers you could also use Truncate instead of Floor.

Comment: Floor won't have the desired result for negative numbers.

Comment: I know and I updated the answer with that information as well

Answer (score -1):

Or another way of doing it, is to use a regex to capture the inputs and convert it back to decimal, for instance

```
Regex r = new Regex("(?<postNo>\d+)\.(?<preNo>\d{1,3})");
Decimal d= 12.159M;
Match m = r.Match(d.ToString());
if (m.Success){
string s = string.Format("{0}.{1}", m.Groups["postNo"].Text, m.Groups["preNo"].Text);
Decimal d = Decimal.Parse(s);
}
```

In the 'preNo' tag in the regex, change it from \d{1,2} for example if you want to keep the digits BUT only two digits alone after the point. Ok, I know people will say, hey that's slow and downvote this answer...it serves to show there are ways to skin a cat!

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

P.S: Have edited this as I realized after a downvote that the edit has escaped the literals that were missing!